# Lisp: Is there any difference between 'nil and nil?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Both

```
(not 'nil)
```

and

```
(not nil)
```

evaluate to `T`, so is there any difference between `'nil` and `nil`? And what about `''nil`? If `''nil` evaluates to `'nil`, shouldn't `''nil` evaluate to `nil` as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(quote <anything>)` evaluates to `<anything>`, literally. The notation `'<anything>` means `(quote <anything>)`, and regardless of what `<anything>` is, it is simply returned without being evaluated.

Furthermore, `nil` evaluates to itself.

Other objects, when quoted as literals, also evaluate to themselves: certain symbols and all non-symbolic atoms are this way.

What is the difference between `'2` and `2`? They both evaluate to `2`!

Also, what is the difference between `'"abc"` and `"abc"`, and between `:foo` and `':foo`?

The difference is that `'2` is the form `(quote 2)` whereas `2` is just `2`. They evaluate to the same thing but aren't the same thing.

To evaluate Lisp means that a datum is treated as the source code of an expression. Two expressions can have the same value, yet be made of different data. For instance `4`, `(+ 2 2)` and `(* 2 2)`.

Say, what's the difference between `4` and `(+ 2 2)`?

If `4` and `(+ 2 2)` both produce 4, why does `'4` produce `4`, but `'(+ 2 2)` produces `(+ 2 2)`?

Quote means, "give me this piece of program code as a datum, rather than the value which it denotes."

Answer (score 6):

When you evaluate `NIL` you get the value of the [variable named NIL](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_nil.htm#nil), and when you evaluate `'NIL` you get the symbol named NIL. However, these two things are defined by the spec to be the same object. See [the Hyperspec on nil](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_n.htm#nil):

> **nil** *n.* the object that is at once the symbol named `"NIL"` in the `COMMON-LISP` package, the empty list, the boolean (or generalized boolean) representing false, and the name of the empty type.

You can check that for yourself:

```
(eq NIL 'NIL) ==> T
```

However, the equivalence stops there. `''NIL` evaluates to the list `(quote NIL)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, as long as you consider only the result of evaluation, i.e.,

```
nil
```

and

```
'nil
```

evaluate to the same value (namely, `nil`). There is, however, a true difference, as far as the reader is concerned, since

```
nil  ===> nil
```

whereas

```
'nil ===> (quote nil)
```

This is interesting in particular, if you have nested forms like

```
((nil) 'nil)
```

which is read as

```
((nil) (quote nil))
```